Initial Refresh Error blocks the Append of Pagination in Compose Android
I attempted to implement pagination using RemoteMediator, but encountered an issue.
The problem: When RemoteMediator performs the initial refresh, if an error occurs (due to a network issue or other reasons), it prevents the pagination from appending. In other words, scrolling to the last item does not trigger an append operation in the RemoteMediator. However, after performing another refresh, everything works as expected.
This issue only happens during the initial refresh.
Is this expected behavior? If so, how should I handle this situation? If not, is there a fix for this?
I'm using Paging 3, Jetpack Compose, and SQLDelight.
code
accessing in ui:
items(users.itemCount) { index ->
    users[index]?.let { user ->  // Safe call with let to handle nullability
        User(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp),
            name = user.name,
            id = user.id
        )
    }
}

Remote mediator:
class UsersPagingMediator(
    private val api: UserApi = ServiceLocator.locate(),
    private val userRepository: UserRepository = ServiceLocator.locate(),
    private val database: MyDatabase = ServiceLocator.locate()
) : RemoteMediator<Int, UserEntity>() {

private val initialRefreshCoolDownTime = 2.minutes

//todo:label as param
override suspend fun initialize(): InitializeAction {
    val lastTimeDataFetched = userRepository.getLastModifiedTimeOfRemoteKey(remoteKeyLabel)
    val elapsedTimeFromLastFetch = lastTimeDataFetched?.let {
        (System.currentTimeMillis() - it).milliseconds
    }
    return if (elapsedTimeFromLastFetch == null || elapsedTimeFromLastFetch > initialRefreshCoolDownTime) {
        InitializeAction.LAUNCH_INITIAL_REFRESH
    } else {
        InitializeAction.SKIP_INITIAL_REFRESH
    }
}

override suspend fun load(
    loadType: LoadType,
    state: PagingState<Int, UserEntity>
): MediatorResult {
    Log.v("tag", "load: $loadType")
    val loadKey = when (loadType) {
        LoadType.REFRESH -> {
            null
        }

        LoadType.PREPEND -> {
            return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
        }

        LoadType.APPEND -> {
            val lastItem = state.lastItemOrNull()
            val remoteKey =
                database.remoteKeyQueries.getRemoteKey(remoteKeyLabel).executeAsOneOrNull()
            Log.v("tag", "handling LoadType.APPEND : $remoteKey")
            remoteKey?.nextKey ?: return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
        }
    }
    return try {
        //api call
        val apiResponse =
            api.getUsers(offset = loadKey?.toInt() ?: 0, size = state.config.pageSize)
                ?: return MediatorResult.Error(Exception("Api response is null"))
        val endOfPagination = apiResponse.size < state.config.pageSize
        //process api data and insert into db
        database.transaction {
            //todo:check if rollbacks and return error
            //clear if refresh, and clear all related dbs
            if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
                userRepository.clearUsers()
                userRepository.deleteRemoteKeyByLabel(remoteKeyLabel)
            }
            //take care of keys(insert new key)
            insertRemoteKey(
                fetchedDataSize = apiResponse.size,
                loadKey = loadKey?.toInt(),
                pageSize = state.config.pageSize
            )
            //insert data into db
            apiResponse.forEach(userRepository::insertUser)
        }
        //return success
        MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = endOfPagination)
    } catch (e: CancellationException) {
        Log.v("tag", "load: $e")
        throw e
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        MediatorResult.Error(e)
    }
}

private fun insertRemoteKey(fetchedDataSize: Int, loadKey: Int?, pageSize: Int) {
    //insert new key
    val remoteKey = when {
        //if api data is empty, then put a null next key
        //this will indicate that there is no more data, we already checked the api
        fetchedDataSize < pageSize -> RemoteKey(
            remoteKeyLabel,
            null,
            null,
            lastModifiedTime =
            System.currentTimeMillis()
        )
        //means we got enough data so put the next offset as nextKey,
        //this will indicate that there might be more data
        else -> RemoteKey(
            remoteKeyLabel,
            null,
            ((loadKey ?: 0) + pageSize).toLong(),
            lastModifiedTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        )
    }
    Log.v("tag", "insertRemoteKey: $remoteKey")
    userRepository.insertRemoteKey(remoteKey)
}

companion object {
    const val remoteKeyLabel = "users"
}
}

